# PHP: socket_read returning only part of response (telnet)

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

My router has an API, where you can connect via Telnet and among other things control an Tellstick.
I'm connecting to the router using PHP.
I can execute commands, but when I'm trying to read the response using `socket_read`, I only get part of it.

This is what it looks like when connected to the router using Windows' telnet function:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tywC7.png.
The response to the command `ts aliases` is several lines long.

When I try to get that response via my PHP script, I just get the first line, `ALIAS=´Hallway´`.

The code I'm using to listen looks like this:

```
function reply($insocket) {

    if (false !== ($bytes = socket_read($insocket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ))) {
        return "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reply: <code>$bytes</code> \n<br>";
    } else {
        return "socket_read() failed; reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($insocket)) . "\n";
    }

    /*
    while ($out = socket_read($insocket, 2048)) {
        return $out;
    }
    */
}
```

All of the code: http://codepad.org/jykGgivv

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting to get the entire message in a single socket_read() call.  With TCP/IP, the traffic can get broken up in unpredictable ways, and you might need to do several several socket_read() calls to get the entire message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its timing out, try something like this at the top of your script:

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);